# import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

Tags: python, mysql

import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
python version-3.7.2

pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

pip install mysql-connector-python 
succesfully installed
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
whereas when I import mysql gives no error message

Comment: Uninstall all the installed `mysql-connector-python` or similar packages. Just install `pip install mysql-connector`. If you have multiple versions of python install you will have to install using `python -m pip install mysql-connector`.

Comment: What is the file name?
You must not name your script ***mysql.py***
Python tries to import mysql from the script and it fail.

Comment: @drew This needs more attention!! Named my file mysql.py and been struggling for an hour thinking there was something wrong with my installation LOL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

resolved by renaming the file to anything else than `MySQL.py` as it just tries to load itself I guess