# Can't import mysql.connector in Python

Tags: python, linux, debian, mysql-connector

As the title says, i can't import mysql.connector in python on **Debian 9.13**

This is what i did

```
# python
 Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on
 linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
 information.
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 450
    f"This connection is using {tls_version} which is now "
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried installing, uninstalling and reinstalling **mysql-connector**, **mysql-connector-python** and **mysql-connector-python-rf** in **Python2.7** and **Python3**

*Before someone flags this question as duplicated, i already tried all the answers in this posts:*

[This connection is using {tls_version} which is now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70460930/this-connection-is-using-tls-version-which-is-now)

[Unresolved import mysql.connector PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835873/unresolved-import-mysql-connector-python)

[import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130245/import-mysql-connector-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysql-connector)

[mysql connector not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61703454/mysql-connector-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)

[This connection is using {tls_version} which is now, unable to deploy Flask application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056329/this-connection-is-using-tls-version-which-is-now-unable-to-deploy-flask-appl)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use "pip3 install mysql.connector" to install the package? Can you also post the python3 trackback for the error?

Comment: The package you have is not designed for Python 2 at all.  Those `f" "` strings were not introduced until Python 3.6.  Note that stock Debian 9 came with Python 3.5; you will need to upgrade to use that package.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. I wasn't aware of it. Cheers.
@ driconmax https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ <- you might need this as well if you are connecting to a MySQL server. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimRoberts and @Dhivakar Chelladurai said in te comments, the solution is to find a version of `MySQL-Connector-Python` for Python2 or Python3.5 max as this is the last version that Debian 9 has for Python3.

1. Download:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python_2.1.8-1debian9_all.deb
```

2. Install:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-connector-python_2.1.8-1debian9_all.deb
```

Thats it!